# Test failing in angular 6 due to APP_BASE_HREF not being set

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, angular6, karma-jasmine

I am starting to use tests in my angular 6 application. I have run into an error though that I am not sure how to solve.

As you can see below my test is complaining that the base href is not set, but in my index.html I do have `<base href="/">`

```
Error: No base href set. Please provide a value for the APP_BASE_HREF token or
       add a base element to the document.
at new PathLocationStrategy (./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js?:498:19)
at provideLocationStrategy (./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js?:5302:9)
at _callFactory (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8735:20)
at _createProviderInstance (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8687:26)
at initNgModule (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:8617:32)
at new NgModuleRef_ (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9343:9)
at createNgModuleRef (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:9332:12)
at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef]
       (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11157:12)
at NgModuleFactory_.create (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js?:11874:25)
at TestBed._initIfNeeded (./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/testing.js?:1015:47)
```

This is my `item-component.spec.ts` test

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {ItemComponent} from './item.component';
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {AppRoutingModule} from '../../app-routing.module';
import {HomeComponent} from '../home/home.component';
import {ContactComponent} from '../contact/contact.component';
import {InventoryComponent} from '../inventory/inventory.component';
import {SearchComponent} from '../search/search.component';
import {ApplicationFormComponent} from '../application/application-form.component';
import {SiteShellComponent} from '../site-shell/site-shell.component';
import {MainNavigationComponent} from '../partials/main-navigation/main-navigation.component';
import {FooterComponent} from '../partials/footer/footer.component';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import {DebugComponent} from '../debug/debug.component';
import {NewformComponent} from '../debug/under-test/newform.component';
import {MultiSelectComponent} from '../debug/under-test/multi-select.component';

describe('ItemComponent', () => {
  let component: ItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ItemComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ItemComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ContactComponent,
        InventoryComponent,
        SearchComponent,
        FinanceApplicationComponent,
        SiteShellComponent,
        MainNavigationComponent,
        FooterComponent,

        DebugComponent,
        NewformComponent,
        MultiSelectComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ItemComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

How come my test cannot see the base href, or what am I doing wrong? I am really not sure what to look at here to fix. I tried importing AppComponent, but that did not help.

Edit: even if someone could not answer but at least point me in the right direction I am quite stuck on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to add this in your module file: import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'; and then provide it in the Providers array of NgModule decorator: providers: [
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }]

Answer (score 3):

Import the RouterTestingModule from @angular/router/testing into the Testbed. That should solve the problem.